# Rendering interval by frames

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I am new here and i hope i am not making anything wrong.
So, my problem is : I want to render my animation, i have 5+ computers to do that and the scene has 2730 frames.
Its possible for example : on computer 1, render from frame 1 to 500; on computer 2 from frame 500 to 1000;on computer 3 from frame 1000 to 1500 and so on ? 
If yes, how can i attach each rendered animation to the other ?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47083/how-to-render-specific-frame-ranges-of-an-animation-in-batch-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option that is available if the machine are on the same network, is to enable placeholders and disable overwrite in the [render output settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/output.html#output-panel), then have each machine render to the same network folder. Each machine can then render the same frame range but each will render different frames.

While getting a little more complex, there is also a [network render](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Net_render) addon included with blender.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the rendered frame range from either the render properties next to dimension settings, or from the time line *Start* and *End* range sliders.

[image]

You should always [render animations to image sequences](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender/15145#15145), and [combine to video afterwards](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52230/how-to-convert-image-sequence-to-video-using-the-vse) in post production.