# Render pass with denoise node not saved when rendering thru command line

Tags: rendering, denoise

I'm a noob Blender user but a long time 3DS Max user.

[image]

1. I have set up render passes to be saved as separate EXR file.
2. All passes render out and saved in the correct place **when test rendering within Blender.**
3. However, because Blender does not support frame range rendering (e.g. frame 0-100 then 200-300), I was forced to use command line to do this. This is where the problem begins.
4. When using command line rendering, all frames are rendered but the AO, DiffInd, & GlossInd pass wont save.
5. I suspect this was due to the denoise node.

It seems command line rendering is buggy when used with denoiser node?

I'm a noob with command line but this is what I used...

blender.exe -b "[file destination]" -s 0 -e 90 -a -s 140 -e 230 -a

Any ideas?

Comment: [This add-on](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/114376/) might help, seems you can set the frame range easily and there is an option to render using the command line as well. Have you already tried that?

Comment: Loom looks great and may sort out the sub-issue of frame range rendering, thx!!! I will check it out and test whether it also sorts out the denoise node issue too? In the meantime, I would still like to understand why the denoise does not save when command line render?