# Is it possible to have an animatable render mask to restrict render area?

Tags: rendering

Let's say I have a scene to render in cycles, and one particular area needs a much large sample rate to achieve satisfying render result. I would like to render the scene in normal sample rate (say, 150), and then I come back to render that particular area with a much higher sample rate (like 500 or higher) with an animated mask so that blender would only render that area. I know there's a mask layer thing in blender but that doesn't stop blender from rendering the whole scene first. I needed something like the render area crop, only animated. Is it possible?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33903/599

Comment: You can use the *Render Border* Addon and animate `Center X` and `Center Y` values, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45837/3710 How much movement is in your scene?

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your scene, you could also just use render layers to Isolate what you are rendering, and composite them together in the Node Editor. (eg. Render Layer #1 gets first pass sampling, then Render Layer #2 get 2nd pass sampling at a higher rate). The major thing to consider is surrounding objects that need to solve for reflection/lighting/etc... If you are going to take this approach, there may just be things that must exist in multiple layers to keep the reflectivity/lighting more true to life.