# How to render individual frames?

Tags: python, rendering, animation

I'm rendering a large animation on a laptop.  And I need to turn off rendering on certain frames (they are repeated).  For example, from 5-10 further from 15-20, 21-25.  I plan to simply duplicate the missing frames rather than render them.
I got acquainted with blender 1 month ago.  sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: There is for sure some script or addon for such thing ... Or you can create a dummy files (just copy files numbered in range you want to skip from any existing image sequence) and under Render Output Properties disable Overwrite checkbox.

Comment: Thank you, I did the same before reading your answer.  I made empty frames and renamed them sequentially.  It's good that I only have ≈100 frames.  I made shortcuts and used the Tab key to sequentially enter the numbers, 0987, 0988, 0989... It's tedious :)But it works

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15649/can-frames-with-no-animation-be-automatically-skipped https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/is-it-possible-to-render-only-keyframes-from-dope-sheet https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39801/can-you-skip-frames-with-no-animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217674/skip-frames-in-rendering https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5010/how-to-render-specific-frames-of-an-animation

Comment: It's crazy, I honestly searched, but didn't come across all this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you render from the command-line you can pass a list of frames that include ranges, like (assuming your last from frame is 250), omitting the frames you don't want rendered:

`blender -b "my.blend" -f 1-4,11-14,26-250`

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately, I have already done as the author wrote above.  Fortunately, there are not many frames.  I still have to master the world of scripts and Python.  I'm pleased with how responsive Blender communities are :)

Comment: @VladimirZhelovanov -- realize that the above is a windows or linux command line, not a python script.  I actually do a lot of my animation rendering using .cmd/.bat files.  These can run in the background ("-b" option above), using less memory (no UI appears).  Here is the [doc](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#command-line-arguments)

Comment: This is the first time I've heard this.  Very interesting, thanks