# Use denoiser on certain frames of animation

Tags: animation, scripting, denoise

Denoiser wastes quite a time on empty renderlayer (about 2 mins for 1080p), but its checkbox can't be keyframed and even LMB's *Copy data path* is greyed out (so, no scripting I guess).

Animating renderlayer visibility is no option for me, because it messes Multilayer EXR a lot.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15649/599

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with this code, where denoiser starts working on specific renderlayer only on certain frames.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene

def denoiser_control (scene): 
if scene.frame_current in list(range(66, 90)) + [1, 20, 50]:
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.layers["RenderLayer"].cycles.use_denoising = True
else:
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.layers["RenderLayer"].cycles.use_denoising = False

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(denoiser_control)
```

**`range(66, 90)`** stands for some frame range and **`[1, 20, 50]`** defines single frames.