# How not to re-render frames in animations that do not change at all (e.g. cache last changed frame)?

Tags: rendering, export, output

I have to render lots of longer animations (1min+).
In many scenes a character moves a little and then stays idle at the same position. During that time NOTHING is changing: No camera movement, no secondary animations, literally NOTHING.
When I render the scenes blender still renders every single frame. So it is basically re-rendering the exact same pixels.
How can I improve this workflow?

I have already tried "Output Properties > Output > Cache Result". That sounds like what I am looking for. But it does not improve my render times at all.

Any hint highly appreciated.

Comment: just a dumb question: if you know it is not doing anything, why do you render them at all? you could render only "changed" frames, and then compose these all in the video editor. Rendering the same frame you get there "for free" by just adding the image and resize the strip.

Comment: This question may be considered a duplicate of: [Can frames with no animation be automatically skipped?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15649/can-frames-with-no-animation-be-automatically-skipped)