# Extra program to use with blender

Tags: animation

Do you know what the name of the program is that lets you import your image sequence into it, and it will create and fill in generated images to fill in between your image sequence you saved from blender?

Comment: You can use the Video Sequence Editor in Blender.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to render only keyframes from Dope-sheet?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1718/is-it-possible-to-render-only-keyframes-from-dope-sheet)

Comment: Looks like the add-on mentioned in that q&a is exactly what you're looking for. *"the addon also provides an utility function to fill the gaps of the image sequence with copies of the nearest frame to get the full lenght animation..."*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mean the application that can increase the framerate of video using AI?

Flowframe

Comment: Yes that's it. Thank you